# Decrypting Drupal / Ubercart Credit Card Info Externally

Tags: drupal, encryption, payment, ubercart

Right now I have a simple PHP script outside of my drupal installation that just compiles a CSV for my client of orders and the credit card type (Visa, Mastercard..)

It seems like an older version of Drupal 6 just had this part of data serialized in the database "cc_card" however now it seems to be encrypted.

Is there a way to decrypt this data (Stored in us_orders.data) so that I could see the card type?

Comment: You have to be careful about regulations, in particular PCI.

Answer (score 1):

The `uc_credit_cache()` function should do what you want:

```
$order = uc_order_load($order_id);
$cc_data = uc_credit_cache('save', $order->data['cc_data'], TRUE);
```

`$cc_data` should look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [cc_type] => visa
    [cc_owner] => 
    [cc_number] => 4111111111111111
    [cc_start_month] => 
    [cc_start_year] => 
    [cc_exp_month] => 9
    [cc_exp_year] => 2012
    [cc_issue] => 
    [cc_cvv] => 222
    [cc_bank] => 
)
```